# jQuery Colour Picker - Dynamic Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-selectors

Hey Guys, basically what im trying to do is use the one instance for all the colour selectors on my page. The code im using is this.

```
$('.color').ColorPicker({ 
        color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) { $(colpkr).fadeIn(500); return false; },
    onHide: function (colpkr) { $(colpkr).fadeOut(500); return false; },
    onChange: function () { $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);}
});
```

The problem is though, the **onChange** function doesnt select **$(this)** as the selector clicked, but changes the colour of the colour picker ui itself.

How do I reference the actual value while still keeping it dynamic to any color selector on the page?

The plugin im using is http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Thanks,
Warren

Comment: have u tried `background-color`  ?>

Comment: btw the `hex` seems a bit odd there :) and `undefined` might be the result

Comment: Everything works fine if I refence the selector by the class its attached, however it then changes the color on the select box on all over the classes with the same name. I want it to only change the box that was selected.

Comment: take a look at the demo. it now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/jquery-colour-picker-dynamic-selector

```
$(function() {
  $('.color').ColorPicker({
  color: '#0000ff',
  onShow: function (colpkr) { $(colpkr).fadeIn(500); return false; },
  onHide: function (colpkr) { $(colpkr).fadeOut(500); return false; },
  onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
    $(el).val(hex);
    $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    $(el).css('backgroundColor', '#' +hex);
  }});  
});
```

Comment: I get 403 errors when it tries to load the colorpicker.* files